# I am trying to create a pop up that will alert user that the site is not for children

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am trying to create a pop-up that will alert users that the site is not for children. I have created the codes but it's not working

HTML

```
  <botton>
    <button data-modal-target="#modal">Open modal</button>
    <div class="modal" id="modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <div class="title">Parental Guidance Required</div>
        <button data-close-button class="close-button">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This website has not been designed for the use of underage children unsupervised. Hence we recommend children be supervised by their parents, guidance, teacher, or another responsible adult. We shall not be responsible for any consequence if this warning is ignored.
    
      </div>
    </div>
      <div id="overlay"></div>

  </botton>
 
  <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>



CSS
```

I am trying to create a pop-up that will alert users that the site is not for children. I have created the codes but it's not working

```
    *,*::after,*::before {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
.modal {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale (0);;
transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
border: 1px solid black;
border-radius: 10px;
z-index: 10;
background-color: white; align-content: center;
width: 500px;
max-width: 80%; 
}

.modal.active {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale (1);;
} 

.modal-header {
padding: 10px 15px;
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
align-items: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid black
}

.modal-header.title {
font-size: 1.25rem;
font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-header .close-button  {
cursor: pointer;
border: none;
outline: none;
background: none;
font-size:1.25rem;
font-weight: bold;
}
.modal-body {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
#overlay {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom: 0
    Background-color rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
    pointer-events none
}

#overlay.active {
opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    
}

}



javascript
```

I am trying to create a pop-up that will alert users that the site is not for children. I have created the codes but it's not working
//modal button
const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-modal-target]')
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-close-button]')
const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay')

```
openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const modal = document.querySelector (button.dataset.modalTarget)
  openModal (modal)
  })
})
overlay.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal.active')
  modals.forEach(modal =>{
    closeModal(modal)
  })
 
})
closeModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click',()=> {
    const modal = button.closest('.modal') 
    closeModal (modal)
    })
  })

function openModal(modal) {
if (modal==null) return
modal.classList.add('active')
overlay.classList.add('active')
}
function closeModal (modal) {
  if (modal==null) return
  modal.classList.remove('active')
  overlay.classList.remove('active')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const openModalButton = document.querySelector("[data-modal-target]");
const closeModalButton = document.querySelector("[data-close-button]");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

openModalButton.addEventListener("click", openModal);

closeModalButton.addEventListener("click", closeModal);

function openModal() {
  modal.classList.add("active");
  overlay.classList.add("active");
}
function closeModal() {
  modal.classList.remove("active");
  overlay.classList.remove("active");
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale (0);
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: white;
  align-content: center;
  width: 500px;
  max-width: 80%;
  display:none;
}

.modal.active {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale (1);
  display:block;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.modal-header.title {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.modal-header .close-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0 Background-color rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) pointer-events none;
}

#overlay.active {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<botton>
  <button data-modal-target="#modal">Open modal</button>
  <div class="modal" id="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="title">Parental Guidance Required</div>
      <button data-close-button class="close-button">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      This website has not been designed for the use of underage children unsupervised. Hence we recommend children be supervised by their parents, guidance, teacher, or another responsible adult. We shall not be responsible for any consequence if this warning is ignored.

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="overlay"></div>

</botton>
```

I removed loops and added display property to modal's active and inactive state in CSS.